# LightWeightChart: How can i add chart which look like this way?

Tags: angular, graph, charts, lightweight-charts

I want to create a chart with lightweight-chart. Two graph sharing same x-axis but both have different values at y-axis mean two pane in single chart. How can i do this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible at the moment, you can subscribe on https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/50 to be notified when it's ready.